# Zend framework error:script 'qa/cre.phtml' not found in path

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm doing a project with zend framework 1.12.

In a action, I just need it ehco a single string '1'.

So I don't want to create the 'phtml' view file.

I wirte action as below:

```
public function creAction()
{
    echo "1";    
}
```

The error is "script 'qa/cre.phtml' not found in path".

So what can I do to fix it without creating the phtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function creAction()
{
    echo "1"; 
   $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
   //or simply use die;
}
```